# Direct Proof Writing Technique

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question, proof-writing

I've been having this proof writing hangup, and the following example covers the essence of it.

In the beginning of my analysis book one of the exercises is:

" If $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a + b = 0$, then $b = -a$. "

Here's the method I used -- and frequently use -- to prove it. I take the given information and derive the desired result.

*Proof*
\begin{align}
a+b &= 0 &&\text{given}\\
(-a)+a + b &= (-a)+0  &&\text{definition of equality}\\
\left((-a)+a\right) + b &= (-a)  &&\text{associativity of addition/zero element}\\
0+b &=-a &&\text{additive inverse}\\
b &= -a &&\text{zero element}\\
\end{align}

But the author uses this other (and much more common) proof style where you start from the left side of the desired result, use some given information, then get the right side.

*Proof*

$$b = 0+b = (-a + a) + b = -a + (a+b) = -a + 0 = -a$$

While I get the aesthetic, I just don't understand why it wouldn't be done the my way, which seems a lot easier. Is one of these styles more correct than the other, or preferred? And if so, why?

P.S. I tagged this as a soft-question in case the answer is subjective.

Comment: This may be off topic, but I wanted to point out that you're using the implication symbol as a substitution for "therefore". This is an incorrect, though very common usage of this symbol. For example,  chaining implications without any parenthesis or grouping indications makes no actual, logically formal sense.

Comment: Why does your way seem a lot easier to you?

Comment: @GuidoA.It is common to write things like $a < b < c < \dots$ as an abbreviation for $a < b \land b < c \land c < \dots$, same for implication or equality.  He isn't incorrect, just using a short hand notion.  It would be no more correct to use any other binary operator.

Comment: The implication mark I don't think is wrong. My way seems easier to me because it just uses algebra. I don't have to try to create a relationship with the given information.

Comment: One notational thing that isn't trivial though, it is important that when you write $a + b - a$ it is an abbreviation for $a + b + (-a)$, and that you are implicitly applying quite a few axioms where as the other proof is applying the axioms explicitly.

Comment: I prefer your version. You assume that the given equation $a+b=0$ is true, then subtract $a$  from both sides to obtain the required result. Much more obvious and straightforward than the second version.

Comment: @DanielV: I believe what Guido A. is talking about is that in a proof where the implication sign is used, it is often the case that not only the statement to the immediate left of the sign is used, but also some or all of the preceding statements are used. Thus, while one might write $A \implies B \implies C \implies D,$ at the 3rd implication we are not always asserting $(C \; \& \; \text{given})\implies D.$ Sometimes we mean $(A \; \& \; B \; \& \; C \;\& \; \text{given}) \implies D.$

Comment: The first proof is lacking a step explicitly noting the associativity of addition.  You are going from $(-a) + (a + b)$ to $(-a + a) + b$.

Comment: Edited. So my proof shows every axiom used. So does the author's. Why is the author's the one we see in textbooks?

Answer (score -1):

The author's style has the benefit of explicitly exhibiting the axioms being used at each step. In fact that is probably the point of the exercise.
Your method leaves out many axioms, esp. in the last step which implicitly implies that $(a+b)-a = b  $ which needs something like commutativity, associativity, inverse, and identity axioms in that order, a sequence of four steps of the kind done by the author.
Your method is probably a good method of discovering the proof, but the author's method is better at showing the reasoning in this case. It is too bad that author's don't take the time to exhibit the difference.
If you claim that you don't need to go thru that axiomatic detail, then you really don't need to do this problem.

Comment: My style, starting with $a +b = 0$, can be shown to use the axioms for each step too. I'm more so looking for opinion on the starting point. The author starts with $b$.

Comment: @Zduff I don't see it in your proof. It seems like you only want confirmation.

Comment: I edited my proof to show the use of the axioms in each step since you couldn't see them before. But now, I want to make my overarching question clear. The author's proof seems unintuitive, he has to create a situation in which to use the given information (i.e. $a + b = 0$) whereas I don't, I simply start with the given information. But I guess that the author had a motivation for doing it the way he did, Rudin does the same in baby Rudin, why? Why this harder version of the proof? Or is my proof invalid?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the form of your proof. Now that you have reformatted it to exhibit the axioms, it is equivalent to the alternative. As you suggest yours seems to have a slight pedagogical advantage. But I think the other has a more attractive and efficient presentation. Chacun son goût.